# Separate Laravel Vue to **only** Vue 2

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, migration, laravel-vue

Basically we already use: API for the routes, and auth-sanctum to login (so I guess it won't be a problem).

How to separate this to backend and frontend?

I already tested this with express (probably not the way to go), could run but I would rather run via npm run dev just like any other Vue project out there.

Below an example, of what we've done, we have to run both npm run hot and npm run serve

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const url = require('url');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
// create new express app and save it as "app"
const app = express();
// server configuration
const PORT = 3000;
// serve static assets
app.use(express.static("public"));
// create a route to serve index.html

const apiProxy = proxy('urlhere/api', {
  proxyReqPathResolver: req => url.parse(req.baseUrl).path
});

// app.use('/api', proxy(process.env.BASE_URL));
app.use('/api/*', apiProxy);

app.get("/", (

req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./index.html", { root: __dirname + "/public/" });
});
// make the server listen to requests
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at: http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

package.json

```
"serve": "node server.js",
"hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
```

public/index.html

```
<body>

  <div id="app"></div>

  <!-- Layout helpers -->
  <!-- <script src="/js/app.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="/bundle.js"></script> -->
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/bundle.js"></script>


  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Separate Laravel Vue to **only** Vue 2" and "How to separate this to backend and frontend?". Do you mean to say separate folder structure and run both on their own independent servers?

Comment: Yeah exacly that, i'm serving via express and using reverse proxies to access the routes but it feels so much hacky

Comment: So is your current structure already mixed like laravel and vue or have you already separated? Also is this only for development purpose?

Comment: It's for production, I already separated and manage to serve it via express, but it makes no sense to me since I have to run both npm run hot and serve, and then do reverse proxies to access the laravel APIs (which still contains both front and back, but I guess separating the backend later is easier).  Currently im having to add all the web.php routes to the proxy

Comment: I adapted this tutorial for my project basically, with some extra steps https://medium.com/@psicliffs/set-up-a-vue-tailwindcss-project-with-laravel-mix-without-vue-cli-facbac8d45df

Comment: Oh i face this kind of issue when using docker, so i had added location config to nginx config and in that i had set proxy headers. Also is it advised to run hot reloading on production server?

Comment: So basically I can't run from reverse proxies? About hot reloading, I guess no? This is so much confusing

Comment: So honestly when you someone else's cookbook you run into this kind of issues, why not, you install laravel and vue-cli by yourself, this way you get to control your app. I am not sure as to why the reference skipped vue-cli, i believe it's much better to use vue-cli

Comment: How would I go about porting my laravel-vue to vue-cli? Any docs I can read?

Comment: Yes so basically you should avoid hot reloading on production servers. Also you need is the vue build to be pulled in to the laravel right? So it honestly doesn't really matter where your build is located at. Some best practices might help you with an answer since they might also give you an answer for your routings

Comment: Actually, I have the build on laravel right now, I want to take it off as front-end only project

Comment: So i did something similar, the answer to this post by @Denis might help with a little tweaks, I had similar nginx config but i used `location /api { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; }` and some other configs as well.

Answer (score 1):

To separate frontend and backend you need a server. A simple solution is nginx. On the frontend you do an `npm run build`. Eventually you have a `dist` folder that should be sent to nginx.

**Here is a sample nginx configuration**

```js
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    server_tokens off;
    root /var/www/front/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;

    access_log vuijs-access.log combined;
    error_log vuijs-error.log error;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8082;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```